# Why are form fields disabled on small screens?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have a Login Form as follows: https://demo.promosi.co/login.
It works normally in browsers such as Firefox and Chrome for Windows. But, I cannot figure out why it is disabled in browsers for Android devices, i.e., I cannot enter the input fields.
The Form is built using Symfony 2.8 with FOSUserBundle. 
Thanks in advance for giving me a clue.

Comment: For the benefit of other users, the question should be: "Why is the web form disabled in small screens?" But, I cannot change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have used the mobile mode of the browsers in the development tools, it would have helped you to know where the problem was coming from.

When the size of the screen is reduced, you have a div (the one with the text "Lupa Password? Silahkan Reset Password") whose height will take that of the screen and put on top of everything else preventing you for example, to click in the fields of the form.

[image: The div with the forgot password link is above the form]

[image]

**To overcome this problem, you must put the 2 divs of the left and right column in another with the class row.**

[image]

PS : It is recommended next time to put the code causing the problem in your question or to use tools like jsfiddle.

Comment: That is exactly the problem, and you have provided a clear solution.